# Accumulated sum using custom Python Expression functions (QGIS3)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3

I'm using PyQGIS within an standalone application. Now I wanted to create a custom expression. How to find the cumulative sum of numbers in a colunm?

```py
camada = iface.activeLayer()    
features = camada.getFeatures()

camada.startEditing()

def sumComprLote(features, lote):

    soma = 0
    for f in features:
        soma = soma + f["comp"]
        print(soma)

   return soma

sumComprLote(features, -1)
```

In the Python Editor, this cumulative sum function performs perfectly, but I need to do it on the Field Calculator (Expression or Function Editor).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following script as a new function: ([How to add custom function](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/tr/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#function-editor))

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

total=0

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def cumulative_sum(field, feature, parent):
    global total
    total += feature[field]
    return total
```

Then you can use it in Expression tab:

```py
cumulative_sum('comp') # don't use double quotes -> "comp"
```

It gives you cumulative sum of given field.

Comment: You’ve really helped me out over! I’m really grateful to you for all your help. Thanks a lot!